# How do I interpret and simulate the extended linux process states?

Tags: linux, process

Here is a snippet of the output of "man proc"

```
   (3) state  %c
                    One of the following characters, indicating process state:

                    R  Running

                    S  Sleeping in an interruptible wait

                    D  Waiting in uninterruptible disk sleep

                    Z  Zombie

                    T  Stopped (on a signal) or (before Linux 2.6.33) trace stopped

                    t  Tracing stop (Linux 2.6.33 onward)

                    W  Paging (only before Linux 2.6.0)

                    X  Dead (from Linux 2.6.0 onward)

                    x  Dead (Linux 2.6.33 to 3.13 only)

                    K  Wakekill (Linux 2.6.33 to 3.13 only)

                    W  Waking (Linux 2.6.33 to 3.13 only)

                    P  Parked (Linux 3.9 to 3.13 only)
```

I have a piece of code that has to read the process states from the /proc/pid/stat. I want to extend it to support the new codes (t,x,K,W[waking] and P)

But now with the necessary changes, I don't know how to simulate these codes. I searched exhaustively for definitions of these states and what conditions triggers them. Can someone point out what each of these new codes mean in real life, so that I can try to simulate the scenarios?

PS: Atleast "t" was observed when debugging the process.